# How to turn on/off fonts anti-aliasing in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, anti-aliasing

Is there a way to turn on/off anti-aliasing in [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad++), either through settings or a certain plug-in?

Comment: Similar to *[Turn off anti-aliasing for text in MS Paint](http://superuser.com/questions/437733)*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notepad++ uses the same settings as the rest of the applications on the system. There isn't any setting within it to change this.

P.S.: If you are having issues with blurry text on DPI settings higher than 96 DPI on Windows Vista/7, turn on "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" on program's "Compatibility" tab.

Answer (score 8):

Settings > Preferences > Editing > Enable smooth font.

Answer (score 0):

After adding a 4K external screen, my *Notepad++* was very blurry on the external screen. The solution for me was to simply edit the **shortcut** to disable the automatic scaling behavior by enabling the override called `High DPI scaling override` and selecting *`Application`* in the drop-down, as shown in the steps below.

---

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had `smooth font` disabled, but the font was still blurry. Turns out there's another setting that used to default to off until recently, and setting it to off restored sharp font for me:
`Settings - Preferences - MISC - Use DirectWrite (May improve rendering special characters, need to restart Notepad++)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).