# Turn off anti-aliasing for text in MS Paint

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-paint

I've been using Microsoft Paint for a project I've been working on many years. I started to work on the project for the first time in almost two years and I've noticed, despite using the same font, size and settings the text I create is anti-aliased.

I'm using MS Paint 6.0.

**EDIT**: I changed my NVidia Driver Settings to this, but it's not working

[image]

Update: I managed to fix this by turning of cleartype, however webpages now look worse.

Comment: Perhaps you could force no AA through your GPU drivers, I know this can be done with Nvidia drivers at least, once you checked use driver preferred setting instead of Applications

Comment: @TheD: I've tried [this](http://i.imgur.com/RNIVY.png) but it's not working

Comment: @Ambo100 If you solved the problem, you can answer your question below

Comment: You need to ensure under global settings that - Applications use the driver setting instead of the application setting I believe.

Comment: @Luke: I haven't solved the problem, yet.

Comment: @TheD: I have done that.

Comment: @Ambo100 Ahhh sorry, misread the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Windows 7 Paint applies Anti Aliasing to everything font related.... woop-de-do! But there is a way to turn this off via a little setting aptly named Smooth Edge.

Open up Advanced System Settings (Right click my computer, properties, then on the left hand side, Advanced Properties).

On the Advanced Tab -> Under Performance, click Settings -> under Visual Effects there is a check box for Smooth edges of screen fonts. That is the only way you can deactivate the AA in Paint, but this is a global setting, so all fonts everywhere won't be Anti-Aliased or 'Smooth Edged'.

[image]

Comment: I've tried this and I'd like to be able to disable AA for paint only.

Comment: Then I believe you will need to move to another Paint distribution like, Paint.net or Gimp.