# How to disable anti-aliasing in Notepad++ 6.7.9.2

Tags: notepad++, anti-aliasing

I recently upgraded Notepad++ from 6.7.8.2 to 6.7.9.2.

Now the content of the documents is anti-aliased. It wasn't the case before.

Note that the only the content of the document is now anti-aliased : the tabs are fine, they are still not anti-aliased.

AFAIK, this is NOT a Windows ClearType issue but purely a Notepadd++ issue, since this Windows setting is still and has always been off on my PC (Windows 7 Pro).

And the solution from [How to turn on/off fonts anti-aliasing in Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/183215/how-to-turn-on-off-fonts-anti-aliasing-in-notepad) does not work.

So what changed between Notepad regarding anti-aliasing ? And more importantly, how do I disable anti-aliasing for Notepad++ ?

Comment: There is nothing in the Notepad++ release notes that refers to a new anti-aliasing setting in recent versions. I checked the notes for each edition from 6.7.8.2 to 6.7.9.2. https://notepad-plus-plus.org/ Don't know what the cause is, but may not actually be Notepad++

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [bug introduced in Notepad++](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/pull/116) that already has a [proposed fix](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/pull/311), which hopefully will be included in the next release. In the meantime, there are workarounds using [Python Script plugin](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/pull/116#issuecomment-113627796) or [NppExec plugin](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/59cc8389#ee6e).

Comment: I can confirm that the problem is fixed in Notepad++ 6.8.